# NoMethodError: undefined method 'load_defaults'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When i upgrade from `rails 4.2` to `rails 5.1` i use `rails app:update`
this add `config.load_defaults 5.1` in `application.rb` when i run `rails db:migrate` this error happend

```
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fe92ab8aa40>
```